# AngularJS maintain service state through page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, service

I'm new to AngularJS and am having some difficulty interacting with my service. I'm sure there are a few things I'm not quite understanding correctly so all advice is welcome.

My Goal: I would like to hold all information pertaining to a user in a single service (provider?). I would like this service to maintain the state of the variables through a page load. I have a login page that redirects to the main page in my app. I would like to save information that is loaded into the service from the login page when I reach the main content page. Currently as soon as the page reloads, my service is set back to default values.

I've done quite a lot of research on this topic, but I think I have more than one issue that needs to be fixed in my AngularJS architecture to accomplish this goal.

AngularJS app:

```
var app = angular.module('AAE', []);

app.provider('userService', function() {
var userModel = {};
userModel.qGroupZero = '';
userModel.qGroupOne = '';
userModel.qGroupTwo = '';

userModel.loadChallengeQuestions = function(userEnrollmentChallenge) {
    this.qGroupZero = userEnrollmentChallenge.challengeQuestions.questionGroup[0];
    this.qGroupOne = userEnrollmentChallenge.challengeQuestions.questionGroup[1];
    this.qGroupTwo = userEnrollmentChallenge.challengeQuestions.questionGroup[2];
};

 this.$get = function() {
     return userModel;
 };
});

app.controller('EnrollmentController', ['$scope', 'userService', '$http', function($scope, userService, $http) { //Dependencies and Constructor function.

    $scope.userService = userService;

    $scope.get = function() {
        return $scope;
    };
}]);
```

My login page is calling loadChallengeQuestions() from a javascript function. Then the app is redirected to the main content page. The state of the variables in my service are not maintained.

I'm 100% certain the answer to my question already exists somewhere, but I could not find it.

**On a side note, when I remove the 'this.$get' function from my userService, I get an error now, previously I didn't have it in my service and it wasnt an issue... Extra credit if you can tell me whats going on there...

Thanks!!

Comment: How are you redirecting to content page after login? If it is a full page refresh then the state cannot be maintained untless you use other methods of storing the state like `cookies` or `localStorage`.

Comment: window.location.replace('url/to/page'); So what I'm trying to do is architecturally wrong? I guess I don't understand what I don't understand. Is my design flawed by wanting to have a user 'model' available on both of my pages, with all information about a user regardless of which page loaded it? and have this model maintain state between the two pages?

Comment: No it's not wrong. It's just another layer of abstraction between your webapp and the db.  It makes a lot of sense. As I said there are already a lot of modules for this purpose, even one implementation of backbone for angularjs.

Answer (score 1):

### To maintain the status across page load

You can use:
- cookies
- localstorage

localstorage is newer but is a better choice compared to the cookies.  The are already some modules for angularjs if you search but you can even use it straight away if you take care to convert the json before to store.

### About your service

In  `loadChallangeQuestons` use the localstorage to store and get the values,  in addition use `UserModel`  instead of `this` .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you're speaking of without using localstorage or some other persistence medium. Redirecting between two html pages will destroy the page (and thus Angular's) context. You could redirect to the login page using a query string of an encoded path of the current page. The login screen would then decode and redirect back to the page after the authentication has been completed. You'd still need to use localstorage to persist any internal state of the service, but you could at least maintain application state using urls.